# JSF 2 form tampering

Tags: security, jsf-2, tampering

I am very new to jsf coming from strust2 just for two days!

As struts automatically bind the request parameters to actions, there was a mechanism to help you control this specially when you used **ModelDriven** approch. There you could implement the **acceptableParameterName** method to take control what should be set automatically by struts and what shall not.

Any way, now we are in JSF and I wonder what shall be done here!

I try below simple page

```
<h:form>
          <h:inputText id="name" value="#{helloBean.name1}"></h:inputText>
            <h:commandButton value="Welcome Me">
               <f:ajax execute="name" render="output" />
            </h:commandButton>

           <h2><h:outputText id="output" value="#{helloBean.name2}" /></h2>
        </h:form>
```

The bean is:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class HelloBean2 implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String name1;
    private String name2;

    public String getName1() {
        return name1;
    }

    public void setName1(String name1) {
        this.name1 = name1;
    }

    public String getName2() {
        return name2;
    }

    public void setName2(String name2) {
        this.name2 = name2;
    }
}
```

I try to tamper the gereated html which was:

```
<input id="j_idt41:name" name="j_idt41:name" value="" type="text">
```

to

```
<input id="j_idt41:name" name="j_idt41:name2" value="" type="text">
```

But no luck and the name2 is not set by JSF

My question is:

Does this means that the JSF know which parameters I try to get from user and automatically prevent others? For example JSF will set **name1** if I have **inputText** with name **name1** ?!

If not, how should I avoid JSF automatically bind not wanted parameters?

Please consider that my real problem is that I want to use the a bean with lots of parameters and only some of them should be set in each view ( some sort of wizard )

I see [In JSF, What is the best way to prevent Form tampering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178237/in-jsf-what-is-the-best-way-to-prevent-form-tampering) but I think my problem is different!

Comment: Your question is not clear: Are you referring to properties of the the component or valuebindings?

Comment: I am referring to value binding. I mean the process which sets the property of managed bean to the inputText.